# Adding Highcharts to Chartkick Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, chartkick

I am trying to add Highcharts to my Rails 4 project that already has the chartkick gem installed.

When I use the Google charting library, all charts seem to function as expected. When I add Highcharts instead, I am not able to see any charts.

I have identified the following:
1) If I add '= javascript_include_tag "components/highcharts.js", "chartkick" ' to my layout footer I am prompted by Rails to also add this asset as an initializer.
2) If I add this to the initializer, I am able to load the page, but charts aren't loaded. If I look in Firebug I get an error stating that Highcharts has been loaded twice.

I have also tried adding Highcharts JS to my application.js, without any luck (The page is loaded, but still no charts are displayed)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download highcharts.js from here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts, you can customize it.

You have to put it on /assets/javascript/ folder of your rails application (saving as .js, do not create new file and copy content).

Now on your view you have to write:

And now you can work with it.